# Limit of an infinite product while x tends to $1^{-}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{1+x^{k+1}}{1+x^k}\right)^{x^k}\right)$

My working: let  $l=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{1+x^{k+1}}{1+x^k}\right)^{x^k}\right)$

$ \ln(l) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k(\ln(1+x^{k+1})-\ln(1+x^{k}))$
$=  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k} (x^{k+1} -x^{k})+ \frac{x^{k}}{2} (x^{2k}-x^{2k+2})+...$

$= \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{x-1}{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^3}+\frac{1}{3} \frac{x^{3}-1}{1-x^4}+...$

$= -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-...$

$= -\frac{1}{2}+\ln(2)-\frac{1}{2} = \ln(2)-1$

$ l= \frac{2}{e} $